# Django template structure issues

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a base.html template that every page on my site will be extending. However, from what I've gathered, Django requires that templates should be in the app directory. From an app, how can I extend a template that I have located in my project's basedirectory/templates/ ?

Here is how my directories are ordered:

```
project/
|----templates/
|    |----base.html
|
|----app1/
|    |----templates/
|         |----app1/
|              |----base.html
|              |----index.html
|
|----app2/...
```

Currently, I have index.html extending app1/base.html:

```
{% extends 'welcome/base.html' %}
```

However, this is not ideal, because I want to extend project/templates/base.html. Logically, my app1 shouldn't have a template in it.

Settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates').replace('\\', '/'),
)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Error is when my app1/views.py tries to render:

```
{% extends 'welcome/base.html' %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `{% extends 'base.html' %}`. All template directories contribute to the same namespace. It doesn't matter in which template directory the base template is, the only thing that matters is its relative path from the template directory.

This is also why you should use a prefix for app-specific templates. If you didn't, and had both `project/templates/base.html` and `app1/templates/base.html`, Django would see them as the same file, with one overriding the other.

The `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting is deprecated in favour of `TEMPLATES`, and if the latter is set, `TEMPLATE_DIRS` is ignored. You should add the directory to `'DIRS'` instead:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, and I get the same error of "TemplateDoesNotExist at /".

Comment: @user3750325 Then you should show the error and your template settings.

Comment: I updated my question to show the settings.py and error!

Comment: Hm, so I deleted TEMPLATE_DIRS and inserted the path into DIRS. However, nothing.

Comment: @user3750325 Does `os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates')` give you the correct path? Make sure to restart your server as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133041/discussion-between-user3750325-and-knbk).